# Error connecting to server localhost on port 1,527 with message Connection refused

Tags: java, hibernate, derby

I have below hibernate configuration.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
   <session-factory>
   <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect</property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver</property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/testdatabase3</property>
   <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

but it is failing with an error message :

```
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1,527 with message Connection refused: connect.
        at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source) ~[time-event-recognition-0.0.8.jar:na]
        at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source) ~[time-event-recognition-0.0.8.jar:na]
        at org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver.connect(Unknown Source) ~[time-event-recognition-0.0.8.jar:na]
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
        at com.zuora.gs.db.DatabaseManager.getDatabaseConnection(DatabaseManager.java:58) ~[time-event-recognition-0.0.8.jar:na]
        at com.zuora.gs.db.DatabaseManager.<init>(DatabaseManager.java:47) ~[time-event-recognition-0.0.8.jar:na]
        at com.zuora.gs.app.main.time.RecogniseEventFile.doMain(RecogniseEventFile.java:147) ~[time-event-recognition-0.0.8.jar:na]
        at com.zuora.gs.app.main.time.RecogniseEventFile.main(RecogniseEventFile.java:57) ~[time-event-recognition-0.0.8.jar:na]
        at com.zuora.gs.app.main.time.RecogniseEventPoller.main(RecogniseEventPoller.java:86) [time-event-recognition-0.0.8.jar:na]
Caused by: org.apache.derby.client.am.DisconnectException: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1,527 with message Connection refused: connect.
```

Please help me what could be the root cause? Thanks!

Comment: are you sure that your DB service is up and running on port 1527 ? try this command `telnet 127.0.0.1 1527`

Comment: @Halayem Anis, Thanks for your reply. Do I need install Derby database?

Comment: Yes of course, you didn't ?